# Adding rewrite rules to Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am currently working on a small WP-Plugin that should include some rewrite rules. For testing purposes I have setup the following functions:

```
function manufacturer_rewrite_add_var($vars) {
  $vars[] = 'manufacturer';
  return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'manufacturer_rewrite_add_var');

function add_manufacturer_rewrite_rule() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%manufacturer%', '([^&]+)');
  add_rewrite_rule(
    '^manufacturer/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?manufacturer=$matches[1]',
    'top'
  );
}
add_action('init', 'add_manufacturer_rewrite_rule');
```

When I activate the Plugin and enter `localhost/manufacturer/audi` I expect to get redirected to the following:`localhost/index.php?manufacturer=audi`. Instead it stays on the same page. What am I missing here?

Comment: Make sure you are not using the **"Post name" setting** in permalinks and that you have re-saved them since your code changes in order to flush the rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule):

> IMPORTANT: Do not forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules database after modifying rules. From WordPress Administration Screens, Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any changes.

You could try using [flush_rewrite_rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules).

> Flushing the rewrite rules is an expensive operation, there are tutorials and examples that suggest executing it on the 'init' hook. This is bad practice. It should be executed either on the 'shutdown' hook, or on plugin/theme (de)activation.

So you could use the function [register_activation_hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) and [register_desactivation_hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_deactivation_hook) to flush it on plugin activation and deactivation.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't get "redirected". It's a rewrite rule, not a redirect rule. Wordpress takes the matched regex from your url and rewrites it internally to the 'manufacturer' query var. And then you can expose the value of 'manufacturer' to your script with [`get_query_var()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/).